WordPress Botiga Theme: Mobile Buttons Not Responsive, Works on PC - Lightspeed Caching Enabled
I'm currently building an website on WordPress (Botiga theme). all was good, there were no issues with the site functionality, payments tested and I was about to go forward with the website. but suddenly buttons stopped working on mobile devices. no PC's no issues, but on mobile it is not responsive. sometimes couple of buttons working and next you try it doesn't. could you please help me on the regards?
i tried to see if its related to cheche on the browser. so, i cleared it and tried but still its the same, tried using different devices and networks as well. and i'm using lightspeed caching, i turned off the "lazy Loading" and tried its the same. i'm not a expert on this domain. so, im confused on what to do next.
